# Objects follow responsive background-image

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a banner image which will include "points of interests" that you can hover over to see more. These points need to have a fixed position relative to the background-image. This is of couse easy if the background-image has a static size, but this need to be responsive with the effect of background-size: cover.

I've tried positioning them both with pixels and percentage, but since background-size: cover alters both witdh and height of the image, this becomes difficult.

Anyone have any solution to this?

I'll inlude a little Jsfiddle so you can see what i mean:

https://jsfiddle.net/jynf21kw/1/

```css
body{
        margin:auto;
        text-align: centeR;
    }
    .background{
        
    }
    .bg{
        background-size:cover;
        height:500px;
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .poi{
        height:50px;
        width:50px;
        position:absolute;
    }
    .poi:after{
        font-family: FontAwesome;
       content: "\f067";
       color:green;
       font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="no">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
    
    </style>
</head>

<body>

 <header id="header" class="header">
     <h1>Header</h1>
 </header>


 <div class="background">
    <div class="bg"  style="background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/HmjQ2tj.jpg');">
        <div class="poi-container">
            <div class="poi" style="left:33%;top:33%;"></div>
            <div class="poi" style="left:564px;top:497px;"></div>
            <div class="poi" style="left:1132px;top:36px;"></div>
            <div class="poi" style="left:1332px;top:336px;"></div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>

<section class="other">
   <h2>Some other content</h2>
</section>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you can try media queries for responsiveness

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that *not* using a background image is ideal but,instead, using an inline image with pins positioned on top.

The image is then made responsive in the usual way and the pins / markers can be positioned absolutely in relation to the image wrapper.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.map {
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
}
.map img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
.box {
  width: 5%;
  height: 5%;
  background-image: url(http://www.clker.com/cliparts/W/0/g/a/W/E/map-pin-red.svg);
  background-position: top center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  position: absolute;
}
#pin-1 {
  top: 25%;
  left: 36%;
}
.box:hover > .pin-text {
  display: block;
}
.pin-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  left: 75%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: none;
}
.pin-text h3 {
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="map">
  <img src="http://connect.homes.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/200392710-0012.jpg" alt="" />
  <div id="pin-1" class="box">
    <div class="pin-text">
      <h3>My House</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```