# Responsive Image with Pins - Part II

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm a newbie. I apologize if this isn't clear.

I'm trying to figure out how to make an image responsive horizontally but also vertically WITH pins ontop of the image that scale to match the picture (not the viewport).

I found the below post, which is perfect for what I'm attempting, *except* the image doesn't fit vertically within the viewport (i.e., there is a vertical scrollbar in a small brower window).

[Objects follow responsive background-image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35599939/objects-follow-responsive-background-image)

I can resize the image how I want by adding vw and vh to the container housing the image, but the pins then move with respect to the viewport and not the image. Does anyone know how to amend the code in the post above to make the picture of the houses fit fully inside the viewport while keeping the pins in place - i.e, on the same house?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

`overflow: hidden`

https://jsfiddle.net/jynf21kw/2/